# Duplicate Entries MySQL with large data?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the follow query to try and identify data from a table with around 10 million rows

```
  SELECT *
FROM
  db.tablename x
JOIN db.tablename z
  ON x.columnA = z.columnA
WHERE
  x.columnB > z.columnB
```

The problem is that the table doesn't have a Primary Key because of the duplicated data in the value that is the primaryKey. The above query is hugely slow and there isn't any way I can figure out how to make it more efficient.

Adding `LIMIT 100` still doesn't seem to help ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the duplicate values you could:

```
select   columnA
from     table
group by columnA
having   count(*) > 1
```

Depending on what you then want to do you could put this in a temporary table.

But it seems strange that you have a concept of identity (even if not 100% correct all the time) and don't have an index on the data - would you not want to do lookups using this field fairly often? Perhaps you could create a non-unique index on columnA, at least while you run your query

Comment: yeah i think I need to create an index across a unique column I have - the problem is I was dumped with all this data and have to figure it out :)

Comment: I might create ALTER TABLE db.name ADD INDEX index.name (column); and then use this ? assume this would speed the scenario up ?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, adding an index like that will greatly improve performance of the above query.

Comment: What if you need to find duplicates in a combination of columns? columnA and columnB. Ie. entries in columnA and columnB but combination of entries in columnA and B cannot be repeated.